# Limit Extent of OpenLayers Map in QGis

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, openlayers-2

I am trying to work with a OpenStreet map of Ontario, using the OpenLayers plugin. The problem is that the entire global view renders, slowing down my work.

A couple of solutions come to mind:

1. Render only the extent of the Ontario shapefile
2. Limit my ability to zoom out past a view of Ontario, but keep the ability to zoom in. I don't know if this can be done at a project level, or at the layer level.

1 would be the ideal solution. For 2, I've discovered that I can limit the minimum scale visibility, but this brings in other complications:

- It lets me zoom out 'past' the visible layer extent. What I would prefer is a hard stop, where I would be unable to scroll out farther.
- It lets me scroll up/down/left/right of the view of Ontario. Is this possible to limit?